# How to replace NewLine in .NET for Linux NewLine

Tags: c#, .net, newline, line-breaks

I have a string in .NET defined like this:

```
var str = @"line 1
line 2
line 3";
```

I want to replace the Windows newline character for the Linux equivalent. (replacing `\r\n` for just `\n`).

I tried `var str2 = str.replace(Environment.NewLine, "\n");` but the result is exactly the same string (str == str2 is true).

I guess that Windows replaces `\n` in strings with `\r\n`, effectively changing nothing.

I tried `var str2 = str.replace(Environment.NewLine, '\n');` but gives compilation errors because one parameter is a string and the other is a char.

I even tried `var str2 = str.replace(Environment.NewLine, '\n'.ToString());` but that did not work either.

Ideas?

Comment: have you tried `str.Replace("\r", "");`?

Comment: A) Are you sure it’s broken in the first place and B) are you writing this to a file? `"\n"` is definitely not translated to `"\r\n"` automatically.

Comment: If you want to replace "\r\n" with "\n", you should be explicit about that. `Environment.NewLine` may be different per, well, environment.

Comment: @Vache ok, I grant you that. It seems that I have no \r\n in the first place so it was my mistake. But... since when newline in windows is just "\n"? I am doing this to create a MemoryStream that will be fed to a library that I need to check against Linux and Windows eol

Comment: @Fernando I actually have no idea why. Sounds like a good idea for a new question. :)

Comment: I get the point from @Vache in DotNetFiddle, but when I try it myself in my laptop, I do have \r\n.

Comment: Yeah-- indeed, I'm not seeing the same behavior.  I'm in VC# Express, .net 4.5, and "Environment.NewLine" is behaving identically to "\r\n" for string replacement.  I don't get the strings as equal.

Comment: And if I paste my code into DotNetFiddle, I do get the same result as @Vache...  seems like a limitation of DotNetFiddle that it does not treat this the same as VS.

Comment: What environment are you using, @Fernando?

Comment: IdeOne has yet another result: http://ideone.com/uWKkTl

Comment: I don't know how to tell you my environment.. but maybe this can help: OSVersion = Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack Environment.NewLine = "\r\n"

Comment: Sure... I just mean "coding environment", like Visual Studio or Notepad++ or DotNetFiddle....  check out my new answer, after all our discussion.

Comment: @MikeM I am using Visual Studio 2012 Express (web)

Comment: That's surprising... I did not have the problem there.

Comment: Difference between IdeOne and .NETFiddle maybe is because the former is a Unix 2.6.32.46 and the later a Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0

Comment: Hey, @Fernando....  by any chance did you copy-paste your literal?  I can reproduce your result on my Windows 7 laptop if I copy-paste the string to VS.  In Notepad++, I make 2 lines, then force to "UNIX/OSX" line ending, then copy it into Visual Studio.

Comment: No Mike, I wrote it from ground zero. (maybe you and me have some difference because I am inside a vm, but actually, I don't think there is a difference)

Comment: Check it out next time you're on a pure Windows box... maybe if you see a difference you can share what you learn about VM's. This is a great question because it's a little detail that will drive someone nuts. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`str` equals `str2` after replacing because your original string does not contain `\r\n` in the first place.

See this [fiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/a061yr).

The multiline string uses `\n`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it depends rather much on the tool you're working in.
AND, on how you type or paste your literal.

A literal string with a line break seems to vary depending on the tool.
One might worry that Environment.NewLine also might vary on the tool (besides the machine), but I haven't shown that yet.

AND you can also copy & paste a literal with line breaks that are different from what you get hitting "enter"/"return" in the tool.
Fun stuff! :)

When it counts like this, a safe bet across platforms would be to use those literals - such as "\r\n" in C# - in a single-line string and don't use line breaks in the editor.
Or else one could load from a file if that is more convenient for more data.

---

Drop this into VS, and then DotNetFiddle and see different results:

```
        var strMyString = @"start
        asdf
        end";
        byte[] ASCIIValues = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strMyString);
        string strENL = "";
        foreach (byte b in ASCIIValues)
        {
            strENL += b + " ";
        }
        Console.WriteLine("strMyString is as ascii: " + strENL);

        /////////
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
        var str2 = strMyString.Replace("\r","");
        Console.WriteLine("string 2 matches == " + (strMyString == str2).ToString());

        var str3 = strMyString.Replace("\n", "");
        Console.WriteLine("string 3 matches == " + (strMyString == str3).ToString());

        var str4 = strMyString.Replace(Environment.NewLine,"\n");
        Console.WriteLine("string 4 matches == " + (strMyString == str4).ToString());

        var str5 = strMyString.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\r");
        Console.WriteLine("string 4 matches == " + (strMyString == str5).ToString());

        /////////
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
        strENL = "";
        ASCIIValues = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine);

        foreach (byte b in ASCIIValues)
        {
            strENL += b;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Environment.NewLine is as ascii: " + strENL);

        /////////


        Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
        Console.WriteLine((Environment.NewLine == "\n").ToString());
        Console.WriteLine((Environment.NewLine == "\r").ToString());
        Console.WriteLine((Environment.NewLine == "\r\n").ToString());
```

Comment: `Environment.NewLine` is platform dependant (as hinted by the name!) and its values are documented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Indeed.  Note how even the line break itself changes.  In VS it is "\r\n".  In DotNetFiddle, it is "\n" alone.

Comment: @Vache -- I love these details with data processing :)  ... I found out how to reproduce Fernando's behavior... copy-paste locally, such as Notepad++ with forcing endings to \n only ("UNIX/OSX").